# Finding $P(N>E(N))$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

I know how to do the **(i)** and I will put out the results, just in case the second part is related to the first part answers.

The C.D.F :

$$F(t) = 1 – (t – 1)^{-2}$$

$P(T>5)$ :

$$= 1 – F(5) = 1 – (1 – 4^{-2}) = 1/16$$

---

Now how to do the (ii) part, I don't understand. Please help. I think N has a different  distribution, but can't figure this out.

Comment: Did you find P(N>E(N))?

Comment: Unfortunately no @Did , even though I accepted an answer :/ didnt fully understand.

Comment: Surely you understand that accepting an answer is sending the message to the world that the question is completely solved to your full satisfaction and that you wish everybody to move on? Judging from the text of your question, I thought the answer was not enough to lead you to a full solution, hence my first comment. Apparently I was right, what do we do know?

Comment: Continuing the mind reading, I note that each answer below is upvoted once, although one of them uses P for N and, IMHO, contains no practical usable advice. Upvoting an answer you accept is only logical but, as the OP, you have no obligation to upvote *everything* posted as an answer to your question.

Comment: *now, not know. Sorry.

Comment: @Did , Understoood, I won't repeat these mistakes :) And I solved this problem :) I found it, with a little help from someone on the chat of math stack exchange, and then he gave me hints, and I solved it finally. Thank You Did.

Comment: @Did , Also if you will add the proper answer to this question, I can accept it and it would be helpful for further students who search for such a problem and lands on this.

Comment: @Did, You are a great mind reader ;)

Comment: If you solved the question, the best thing to do is to post your own answer (and even, after a while, and if, at the end, your answer is the one you like best, to accept it).

Comment: Are you sure that's fine to accept my own question? One may find it as if I am cheating for reputation by asking and answering and accepting it.

Comment: Definitely--it is even *explicitely recommended* somewhere in the instructions/howto pages (but be ready to see your solution being dissected and critiqued just like every other solution...).

Comment: Sure @Did ;) If you say so.

Comment: @Did, I answered it ;) Please check :) If there are inportant notes to add :) Please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we know that $P(T>5)= \frac{1}{16}$ from the (i)

Thus, for the distribution of $N$, the probability of success is $p= \frac{1}{16}$.

We know that $N$ follows a geometric distribution: $P(N=n)=p (1-p)^{n-1}$, and for a geometric distribution, $E(N)=\frac{1}{p}=16$.

Now, we want to find $P(N>16)$, which is the sum of all probabilities from $17$ to infinity (since $N$ is discrete), that is

$$\sum_{17}^{\infty} p (1-p)^{n-1}$$

This is the sum of a geometric progression, 
where the first term is $a = p(1-p)^{16}$ and the common ratio is $r= 1-p$. Thus,

$$\sum_{17}^{\infty} p (1-p)^{n-1} = \frac{a}{1-r}=(1-p)^{16},$$ that is, finally, $$P(N\gt E(N))=\left(1-\frac1{16}\right)^{16}\approx0.356$$

Answer (score 2):

$1_{T>5}$ is a Bernoulli variable, you already know its probability from (i),  let us denote it $p$.

Prove that 
$P(N=n)=(1-p)^{n-1} p$, then compute $E(N)$, then $\Pr(N>E(N)) = 1- \Pr(N \leq E(N))$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint : P follows a Geometric Distribution.**

Find the distribution of N and then find the Expected value in the normal way. and then use that  to find the probability.